# Building a project depending on ros.org platform

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ros and trying to do:

```
 cmake CMakeLists.txt
```

this file includes some ros libraries but I have an error:

```
[rosbuild] Building package mypackage
CMake Error at /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:119 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "mypackage" at "", but the current
  directory is "/home/mypackage/code".  You should
  double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the
  correct precedence order.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/cturtle/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:157 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
```

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12088/building-a-project-depending-on-ros.org-platform/) by [Belal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1439/belal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you go through the beginner tutorials? That should tell you how to properly make a ROS package.

From your error messages:

1. Don't call cmake directly. Use make or rosmake.
2. Are you using cturtle? I think you system setup might be inconsistent.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0